# How to return ISO date format in PHP for MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, date, time, isodate

I want to store the current date generated from PHP into MongoDB collection as an ISO date formate.

```
ISODate("2012-11-02T08:40:12.569Z")
```

However I am not able to generate such Kind of **date** in php which will be stored in MongoDB as an **ISODate** format.

This is what I ve done.

```
 $d = new MongoDate(time());
 echo $d;
```

and it is outputting something like,

```
0.00000000 1353305590
```

which is not the format I need. How to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could run the `__toString` function, or use the `sec` field

`__toString` will return a timestamp in usecs, which you can pass to `date()` after separating the seconds from milliseconds - read here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodate.tostring.php

OR, I personally prefer to have mongodb return just the seconds, which can be plugged directly into `date()` - read here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php

Also, if you're generating a MongoDate() for right now, you don't need to specify time();

In order to return an isodate, you need to do this:

```
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, (new MongoDate())->sec);
```

...

```
$exampleDate = new MongoDate();
echo date(DATE_ISO8601, $exampleDate->sec);
```

EDIT: To save your ISO date, you need to do the following:

```
$mongoDateObject = new MongoDate(strtotime("2012-11-02T08:40:12.569Z"));
```

Comment: but if i store the result in a collection, will it get stored as ISODate("2012-11-02T08:40:12.569Z") or simply 2012-11-02T08:40:12.569Z ???

Comment: I misread your original question. Sorry about that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, let's consider the following use case:

You need to convert a string in the **simplified extended ISO 8601 format** (e.g. returned by Javascript's `Date.prototype.toISOString()`) to and from PHP's `MongoDate` object, while preserving maximum precision during conversion.

In this format, the string is always 24 characters long: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`. The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix `Z`.

To keep milliseconds, we'll have to leverage PHP's `DateTime` object.

**From string to `MongoDate`**:

```
$stringDt =  "2015-10-07T14:28:41.545Z";
```

*Method 1* (using `date_create_from_format`):

```
$phpDt = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $stringDt);
$MongoDt = new \MongoDate($phpDt->getTimestamp(), $phpDt->format('u'));
```

*Method 2* (using `strtotime`):

```
$MongoDt= new \MongoDate(strtotime ($stringDt),
   1000*intval(substr($stringDt, -4, 3)) // cut msec portion, convert msec to usec
);
```

**From `MongoDate` to string**:

```
$MongoDt = new \MongoDate(); // let's take now for example
$stringDt =
   substr(
      (new \DateTime())
       ->setTimestamp($MongoDt->sec)
       ->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))
       ->format(\DateTime::ISO8601),
   0, -5)  // taking the beginning of DateTime::ISO8601-formatted string
   .sprintf('.%03dZ', $MongoDt->usec / 1000); // adding msec portion, converting usec to msec
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked great for me thanks. I was passing a date search query through a private API I developed, and needed to pass a date. I was able to use your date format and extended JSON to pass mongo Date objects through to my API properly: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Answer (score 2):

```
convert ISO date time in UTC date time here :


$timestamp = $quicky_created_date->__toString(); //ISO DATE Return form mongo database
$utcdatetime = new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($timestamp);
$datetime = $utcdatetime->toDateTime();
$time=$datetime->format(DATE_RSS);
$dateInUTC=$time;
$time = strtotime($dateInUTC.' UTC');
$dateInLocal = date("d M Y", $time);
echo $dateInLocal; die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert ISODate time by using below code.

```
   * return ISO-8601 date format:YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssXXX , for example: 2015-09-07T10:13:45.110-07:00 .
   */

date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000P", strtotime($date));
```