# date output in laravel/mongdb lots of zeros in front of the date

Tags: mongodb, laravel, date, date-formatting

Im trying to output a date from my database but i get lots of 0 in front of the date.

```
foreach($datas as $data){
    echo $data['date'];
}
```

my output is 0.00000000 1561828107
why is that?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448614/how-to-return-iso-date-format-in-php-for-mongodb/13448657

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return ISO date format in PHP for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448614/how-to-return-iso-date-format-in-php-for-mongodb)

Comment: I found the solution thanks